# Perforce Changelist Summary

Tags: perforce, changelist, revision-history

Does anyone know how to get perforce to generate a table of the details and descriptions of a file's history?

Either GUI or command line solutions are OK.  On the P4V GUI windows client, when you right-click on a file in the work space tree view, and select "File History", you can see a list of every revision, with Description as the last column in this list.  I would love to just print this list out in a printer friendly format (because if there is a long description it never fits on the screen).

Basically I need a nice neat list of every change to a file, with date, and a description of the change.  I have not found a way for perforce to generate this printable list, other than in the "File History", but this is not printable besides using the snipping tool or print screen, which i do not want to use.

The best case scenario would be a list with the date and description, and also a summary of the diff-against analysis, to show exactly what was changed in each revision for a particular file.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could could try using [P4Report](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/tools_utilities/tools_utilities)* to create a report that directly queries this information from the Perforce. It does this by providing an ODBC data source which integrates into a number of reporting programs, e.g. Crystal Reports, Microsoft Excel etc.

I have not used it myself before, however given the opportunity I would do so over writing a custom script.

There is some [documentation in the Perforce manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4report/01_install.html) on getting it set up and there is plenty of tutorials/information on consuming data sources in Microsoft Excel.

From your other questions/answers, I can see that you know how use an ODBC data source so *P4Reports* should provide you what you need. As for the actual p4 commands you need, see [Karl Bielefeldt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181412/73025).

<sub>* It is about half-way down the page amongst the other *Tools & Utilities*</sub>

Comment: Wow this is awesome, I can use SQL to query the perforce data!! Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

`p4 changes -l <filename>` will give you this info on the CLI.  I believe the only way to get the individual diff-against info would be to write a script that runs `p4 describe` on every relevant changelist.